# Form inside a backend component redirects me to index page

Tags: joomla-2.5, component, development, form

I got the function addNew() that creates a form inside a backend component.

```
function addNew() {

    $route= JRoute::_( 'index.php?option=com_pelatol&task=insertyo');
    $html.='<form action="'.$route.'" method="GET" ><div><h3>Εισαγωγή Ακινήτων</h3>';
    //$html.='<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_pelatol" />';
    //$html.='<input type="hidden" name="task" value="insertyo" />';

    $html.='<br/><span>Περιοχή</span></br><input type="text" name="perioxi" />';
    $html.='<br/><span>Εμβαδόν</span></br><input type="text" name="embado" />';
    $html.='<br/><span>Υπνοδομάτια</span></br><input type="text" name="ipnodomatia" />';
    $html.='<br/><span>Μπάνια</span></br><input type="text" name="mpania" />';
    $html.='<br/><span>Έτος</span></br><select>';
    $cYear=date("Y");


    for ($i=1950;$i<=$cYear;$i++) {

        $html.='<option value="'.$i.'">- '.$i.' -</option>';
    }
    $html.='</select>';
    $html.='<br/><span>Θέρμανση</span></br><input type="text" name="thermansi" />';
    $html.='<br/><span>Διαθέσιμο</span></br><input type="text" name="diathesimo" />';
    $html.='<br/><span>Οδός</span></br><input type="text" name="odos" />';
    $html.='<br/><span>Τιμή</span></br><input type="text" name="timi" />';
    $html.='</div><input type="submit"/></form>';
    echo $html;
}



function insertyo() {
   $session =& JFactory::getSession();
   var_dump($_GET);
   //$session->get( 'perioxi' )



}
```

When I click the submit button the URL I'm getting redirected is : administrator/index.php?perioxi=asdas&embado=asdasd&ipnodomatia=adasd&mpania=asdasdas&thermansi=asdasd&diathesimo=asdasd&odos=asdasd&timi=asd. It ignores the `?option=com_pelatol&task=insertyo` statement of Jroute. I'm currently using a "hack" to achieve the desired output:

```
//$html.='<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_pelatol" />';
//$html.='<input type="hidden" name="task" value="insertyo" />';
```

I'm sure there is another way. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why did you comment `option` and `task` hidden inputs?

Answer (score 1):

You should change `method="GET"` to `method="POST"`.

[HTML  method Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)

Comment: Why should i use post when i dont send sensitive data? Is it mandatory inside the component ??